# how to find the sum of all the prime numbers between 1 and 50 in java?

Tags: java

i have the following code, but the answer is coming out to be 2.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 2; i <= 50; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.println(j);
                if(i % j == 0) {

                    count++;
                }
                if(count == 2) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    sum = sum + i;
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println("The sum: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to stick to your current logic: you need to move `count` declaration inside the outer loop and then move the `if count` check after the inner loop.

Comment: The sum of all primes between 1 and 50 is a constant... So why write code for it?

Comment: In the spirit of @Yunnosch comment:  `System.out.println("The sum: 328");`

Comment: Oh come on, I'm pretty sure we understand the assignment and its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You were close.  But here is all you need.

- first, set sum to 2.  It is the only even prime and doing this allows a better increment below
- now increment the test cases starting at 3 and incrementing by 2.  Skip even values.
- now divide by each test case by numbers from 2 to the `sqrt(i)`.  No need to go beyond that.
- as soon as you have a successful division, end the inner loop and start the next of the outer loop.
- otherwise, if the inner loop completes, add `i` to sum.

```
int sum = 2;
outer:
for(int i = 3; i <= 50; i+= 2) {
    for(int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
        if(i % j == 0) {
            continue outer;
        }
    }
    sum += i;
}
System.out.println("The sum: " + sum);
```

An improvement would be to store the primes as they are found and then only divide by those instead of arbitrary numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this code was written by Github Copilot with minimal supervision.

```java
class Scratch {

    // find the sum of all prime numbers between 2 and n
    public static int sumPrimes(int n) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    // return true if n is prime
    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // print sum of primes between 2 and 50
        System.out.println("The sum: " + sumPrimes(50));

    }
}
```

Prints:

```
The sum: 328
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a minimal version with recursive method based on Aivean response:

```
class Scratch {
    // find the sum of all prime numbers between 2 and n
    public static int sumPrimes(int n) {
        if (n >= 2) {
            return (isPrime(n) ? n : 0) + sumPrimes(n-1);
        }
        
        return 0;
    }

    // return true if n is prime
    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // print sum of primes between 2 and 50
        System.out.println("The sum: " + sumPrimes(50));

    }
}
```